# How can I make VSCode recognize my TypeScript imports with Yarn?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, importerror

I am using TypeScript and trying to make VSCode recognize the `uuid` module that I've imported with Yarn.

The problem is that its not finding the module or its type declarations after I've imported them as seen below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**does anyone know the fix to this?**

Comment: try to restart/reopen your editor

Comment: restarting my entire pc didnt fix it @AshotAleqsanyan

Comment: you installed the package right?

Comment: yes, I did add the package @AshotAleqsanyan

Comment: Which version of Yarn are you using? What does you `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: @j1mbl3s u dont know which version im using but the tsconfig.json looks like this:

`{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "lib": ["ESNext"],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "target": "ESNext",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true,
  "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
  "resolveJsonModule": true
 },
 "include": ["src"],
 "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}`